# Bijection between algebraic subsets and radical ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I want to prove a proposition given in abstract algebra:

Let k to be an algebraically closed field. If X is an algebraic set, $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}_{k}^{n}$, prove that there is a bijection between algebraic subsets of X an the radical idelas of $\mathcal{A}(X)$, where $\mathcal{A}(X)$ is the coordinate ring of X.

Then, prove that exist a correspondence between irreductibles subsets of X and their prime ideals.

Finally, if $Y\subseteq X \subseteq \mathbb{A}_{k}^{n}$ are algebraic subsets, and we define $I_X(Y) := \{ f \in \mathcal{A}(X) : f(p)=0 \forall p \in Y \}\subseteq \mathcal{A}(X)$, prove that $\mathcal{A}(Y) \cong \mathcal{A}(X)/I_X(Y)$.

Comment: This is worked out in detail in basically every introductory algebraic geometry text. Have you consulted any of them?

Comment: @KReiser I've tried it consulting Introduction to Commutative Algebra by Atiyah and MacDonald.

Comment: And what happened when you did that? Where did you get stuck, and what did you try? Here at MSE, you are expected to [include your thoughts and attempts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) on a problem, otherwise your post will be downvoted and closed.

Comment: @KReiser Well I've tried to prove the first question using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, assigning to each radical ideal I the set of points that vanished every polynomial in it V(I), but I don´t know if it is an algebraic subset, Moreover, I don't understand question 3, I can't find and isomorphism doing what is request.

Comment: This information should go in your post (via an [edit]) so as to be more visible to answerers. If you're not sure about whether something is an algebraic subset, you ought to include the definition and what parts of that definition you're finding it hard to verify. Further details on what you've tried and where you're stuck will make it more likely for you to get the help you need!